# Create a m3u8 file with several qualities using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, http-live-streaming, m3u8

I would like to create a m3u8 file like this one using ffmpeg (with all its qualities)

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=590000,RESOLUTION=480x270,CODECS="mp4a.40.2,avc1.77.30",CLOSED-CAPTIONS=NONE
https://videos-f.jwpsrv.com/content/conversions/LOPLPiDX/videos/jumBvHdL-24721146.mp4.m3u8?token=0_5b217886_0x0f48d5705daaf23a9dec01a5ef8298523a0565df
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=4300000,RESOLUTION=1920x1080,CODECS="mp4a.40.2,avc1.77.30",CLOSED-CAPTIONS=NONE
https://videos-f.jwpsrv.com/content/conversions/LOPLPiDX/videos/jumBvHdL-24721151.mp4.m3u8?token=0_5b217886_0xdc0d89087f519e76b149d7524f1ace8b2cde710f
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=2050000,RESOLUTION=1280x720,CODECS="mp4a.40.2,avc1.77.30",CLOSED-CAPTIONS=NONE
https://videos-f.jwpsrv.com/content/conversions/LOPLPiDX/videos/jumBvHdL-24721148.mp4.m3u8?token=0_5b217886_0x6bda9f1d380f2a579f3afe5fa771782112210d4a
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=920000,RESOLUTION=720x406,CODECS="mp4a.40.2,avc1.77.30",CLOSED-CAPTIONS=NONE
https://videos-f.jwpsrv.com/content/conversions/LOPLPiDX/videos/jumBvHdL-24721147.mp4.m3u8?token=0_5b217886_0xadf9ee242ffa3ffa30103f2178d9274bd63f0184
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=330000,RESOLUTION=320x180,CODECS="mp4a.40.2,avc1.77.30",CLOSED-CAPTIONS=NONE
https://videos-f.jwpsrv.com/content/conversions/LOPLPiDX/videos/jumBvHdL-24721145.mp4.m3u8?token=0_5b217886_0x7379ef13ee1e9ae13bb015966c2167293eefb451
```

Does anyone know the magic order? (I use a vps that is under ubuntu)
Thank you in advance for any help

Comment: Take a look here: https://gist.github.com/ddennedy/16b7d0c15843829b4dc4

Comment: Thanks but it's not working :(